# Plot a segmented graph with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have plotted the graph attached in the picture but I would like it to be segmented. That means, the x axis between Z and X and between R and M should not show up. Here is my gnuplot script:

```
delt=0.1

x0 = 0.000
x1 = 0.469 
x2 = 0.939
x3 = 1.603
x4 = 2.027
x5 = 2.496
x6 = 2.965
x7 = 3.629
x8 = 4.053
x9 = 4.477

xmin = x0
xmax = x9+2*delt
ymin = -6.0
ymax = 6.0

set yrange [ymin:ymax]
set xrange [xmin:xmax]
set ylabel '{/Symbol e-e}_{Fermi} (eV)'

set xtics ("{/Symbol G}" x0, "X" x1, "M" x2, "{/Symbol G}" x3, "Z" x4, "R" x5, "A" x6, "Z" x7, "X" x7+delt, "R" x8+delt, "M" x8+2*delt, "A" x9+2*delt)
set mytics 2


set arrow nohead from  x0,ymin to x0,ymax lc rgb "grey" lw 1
set arrow nohead from  x1,ymin to x1,ymax lc rgb "grey" lw 1
set arrow nohead from  x2,ymin to x2,ymax lc rgb "grey" lw 1
set arrow nohead from  x3,ymin to x3,ymax lc rgb "grey" lw 1
set arrow nohead from  x4,ymin to x4,ymax lc rgb "grey" lw 1
set arrow nohead from  x5,ymin to x5,ymax lc rgb "grey" lw 1
set arrow nohead from  x6,ymin to x6,ymax lc rgb "grey" lw 1
set arrow nohead from  x7,ymin to x7,ymax lc rgb "black" lw 1
set arrow nohead from x7+delt,ymin to x7+delt,ymax lc rgb "black" lw 1
set arrow nohead from  x8+delt,ymin to x8+delt,ymax lc rgb "black" lw 1
set arrow nohead from x8+2*delt,ymin to x8+2*delt,ymax lc rgb "black" lw 1


plot  'BAND.dat' u ($1<=x7 ? $1 : 1/0):($2-efermi) w l ls 1 notitle, \
 'BAND.dat' u ($1>x7 && $1<=x8 ? ($1+delt) : 1/0):($2-efermi) w l ls 1 notitle, \
 'BAND.dat' u ($1>x8 ? ($1+2*delt) : 1/0):($2-efermi) w l ls 1 notitle
```

Now, I don't know how to hide the x-axis segments.

I have tried with multiplot and adding white-filled rectangles, but it does not work.

Any hint to do this would be welcome.

Thank you
Pascal

[image: attached image]

I would like to hide parts of the x axis. I have tried by adding white-filled rectangles whithout success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A different approach with using `multiplot`:

```
reset
set colors classic

efermi=0.5

x0 = 0.000
x1 = 0.469 
x2 = 0.939
x3 = 1.603
x4 = 2.027
x5 = 2.496
x6 = 2.965
x7 = 3.629
x8 = 4.053
x9 = 4.477

xmin = x0
xmax = x9+2*delt
ymin = -6.0
ymax = 6.0

set yrange [ymin:ymax]
set y2range [ymin:ymax]

set grid xtics lt -1 lc rgb "grey"
set border lw 2

set multiplot

set size x7/(x9+2*delt),1
set origin 0,0

set rmargin 0

set ytics nomirror

set ylabel '{/Symbol e-e}_{Fermi} (eV)'
set xtics ("{/Symbol G}" x0, "X" x1, "M" x2, "{/Symbol G}" x3, "Z" x4, "R" x5, "A" x6, "Z" x7)

plot[xmin:x7]  'BAND.dat' u 1:($2-efermi) w l ls 1 notitle

set size (x8-x7)/(x9+2*delt),1
set origin (x7+delt)/(x9+2*delt),0

set lmargin 0
set rmargin 0

unset ytics
unset ylabel
set xtics ("X" x7, "R" x8)

plot[x7:x8] 'BAND.dat' u 1:($2-efermi) w l ls 1 notitle

set size (x9-x8)/(x9+2*delt),1
set origin (x8+2*delt)/(x9+2*delt),0

set rmargin

set y2tics
set format y2 ""
set xtics ( "M" x8, "A" x9)

plot[x8:x9] 'BAND.dat' u 1:($2-efermi) w l ls 1 notitle

unset multiplot
```

[image: example]

This is not answer to the original question, but I think that is a reliable solution.

Comment: Thank you Tom for your replies. you solved all my problems, including the shifting of graphs and kipping the x-axis scale of the shifted graphs.

Best regards
Pascal

Comment: @Pascal if this answer solved your problems, please check the check mark at the top left indicating that the question is answered.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the top and bottom part of the border and replace them with self-made arrows:

```
set border 10
set arrow nohead from  xmin,ymin to x7,ymin lc rgb "black" lw 2
set arrow nohead from  xmin,ymax to x7,ymax lc rgb "black" lw 2
set arrow nohead from  x7+delt,ymin to x8+delt,ymin lc rgb "black" lw 2
set arrow nohead from  x7+delt,ymax to x8+delt,ymax lc rgb "black" lw 2
set arrow nohead from  x8+2*delt,ymin to xmax,ymin lc rgb "black" lw 2
set arrow nohead from  x8+2*delt,ymax to xmax,ymax lc rgb "black" lw 2
```

[image]

**NOTE 1:** you forgot to define 'efermi'

**NOTE 2:** I have used a simple sin(x) and efermi=0.5 for the example

**NOTE 3:** in the future, you should use `multiplot`